# how to check a pyspark dataframe value against another dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have below pyspark dataframe df and I want to check the id are present in another dataframe df1 and return true and false for every row.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Create SparkSession

data=[["12345","2020-02-01"],["6789","2019-03-01"],["12345","2021-03-01"],["7890",""],["5000","2021-21-01"],["80000","1900-01-01"],["90000","2000-01-01"],["","2000-01-01"]]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,["id","Date"])
df.show()

data=[["12345"],["6789"],["7890"],["90000"]]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(data,["id"])
df1.show()
```

df data frame :

| id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2020-02-01 |
| 6789 | 2019-03-01 |
| 12345 | 2021-03-01 |
| 7890 |  |
| 5000 | 2021-21-01 |
| 80000 | 1900-01-01 |
| 90000 | 2000-01-01 |
|  | 2000-01-01 |

df1 dataframe :

| id |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 6789 |
| 7890 |
| 90000 |

I am looking to get below output based on the comparsion from df with df1.

| id | Check |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | True |
| 6789 | True |
| 12345 | True |
| 7890 | True |
| 5000 | False |
| 80000 | False |
| 90000 | True |
|  | False |

Comment: what have you tried? it's just a simple left join.

Comment: df.join(df1, ['id'], 'left').show()  how do i get true and false values

Comment: just check whether the date is null after joining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as mentioned in the comments, use a left join. First we need to add an
additional column to `df1` which helps us identify the ids that are in `df1`.
Then we coalesce the column to get `True` and `False` values:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.join(df1.withColumn('Check', f.lit(True)), on="id", how='left')\
    .withColumn("Check", f.coalesce("Check", f.lit(False))).show()
```

Results in:

```
+-----+----------+-----+
|   id|      Date|Check|
+-----+----------+-----+
| 5000|2021-21-01|false|
|90000|2000-01-01| true|
| 6789|2019-03-01| true|
| 7890|          | true|
|80000|1900-01-01|false|
|12345|2020-02-01| true|
|12345|2021-03-01| true|
|     |2000-01-01|false|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

The trick is to add the check column to `df1` before the join. Executing

```
df.join(df1.withColumn('Check', f.lit(True)), on="id", how='left')
```

results in :

```
+-----+----------+-----+
|   id|      Date|Check|
+-----+----------+-----+
| 5000|2021-21-01| null|
|90000|2000-01-01| true|
| 6789|2019-03-01| true|
| 7890|          | true|
|80000|1900-01-01| null|
|12345|2020-02-01| true|
|12345|2021-03-01| true|
|     |2000-01-01| null|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

Now we need to coalesce the `Check` column to end up with the desired `True/False` values.